# Invalid address input returned by findTransactions() though TX is avail on thetangle.org

Tags: iri-legacy-api

If I submit my address

```
ZOWKEWUCNRDICY9DWEPWGYCUZBZIFHR9MFK9ECSEDDTWNHVQYYHH9YMTVFODAWEEMNLURHCTXDXPGIVADBCXR9OOCZ
```

at https://thetangle.org/ I get all the details for TXs on this address.

However, if I submit an API request against my fully synced Full Node, the response is "Invalid address input".

```
curl http://localhost:14265 \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-IOTA-API-Version: 1' \
  -d '{"command": "findTransactions", "addresses": ["ZOWKEWUCNRDICY9DWEPWGYCUZBZIFHR9MFK9ECSEDDTWNHVQYYHH9YMTVFODAWEEMNLURHCTXDXPGIVADBCXR9OOCZ"]}'
```

The address has not been created / used prior to a different snapshot. It's a current address at the time of this writing.

How does The Tangle get the details? Do they have access to some sort of private API? Is there anything wrong with how I submit the API call?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can be edited somehow to be of use to future users even though it's based on a misunderstanding of the actual address.

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem myself. Addresses must be 81 in length. The address above has a length of 90 because it includes the checksum. The Tangle obviously is clever enough to strip the last 9 digits.